# How can I perform a global replace on a variable?

Tags: javascript

I have a basic replace function, but I need it to perform a global replace, as it seems to be stopping on the first instance. I do not want to do it with a Regex. Applying the global attribute seems easy enough in most examples, but I am passing in a variable as the value to be replaced, and /g is having no impact. What am I doing wrong? Here is the example without the /g:

**test string**

```
"Why is my ^%friend so ^%? Maybe I need a ^!% one, abrand^!% one"
```

**Simple replace function**

```
function translate(oddStr) {
    var tagDictionary = {};
        tagDictionary['^%'] = 'odd';
        tagDictionary['^!%'] = 'new';

    Object.keys(tagDictionary).forEach( function (tag) {
        oddStr = oddStr.replace(tag, tagDictionary[tag]);
    });

    return oddStr;
};
```

This function returns the first instance of each replaced, as expected. How can I apply /g to the tag variable in the forEach?

Comment: No, that was my first attempt

Comment: did the below solved your question?

Comment: Try creating the regex first using the variable and the global option... like they do here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/494046/398606

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `split`-`join` combo like this:

```
oddStr = oddStr.split(tag).join(tagDictionary[tag]);
```

Comment: I have upvoted and accepted this as my answer. My reasoning for this is that I said I wanted to do this without Regex, and this is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
"Why is my ^% friend so ^%? Maybe I need a ^!% one, abrand ^!% one".replace(/\^%/g, 'odd').replace(/\^!%/g, 'new')

"Why is my odd friend so odd? Maybe I need a new one, abrand new one"
```

If you need to create the regular expression from string, you can use `RegExp` constructor: `new RegExp('\\^%', 'g')`.

If you don't have control over the tag-dictionary and it is coming from some external resource, then you will have to [properly escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) the tags.

Instead of using adhoc symbols for templating you should ideally use something like [lodash.template](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.template)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your regex special characters (`^`=Start of string)

```js
function translate(oddStr) {

  var tagDictionary = {
    '\\^%'  : "odd",
    '\\^!%' : 'new'
  };

  Object.keys(tagDictionary).forEach( function (tag) {
    var r = new RegExp(tag, "g");
    oddStr = oddStr.replace(r, tagDictionary[tag]);
  });

  return oddStr;
};



console.log(translate("Why is my ^%friend so ^%? Maybe I need a ^!% one, a brand ^!% one"));
```